# Cost function convergence in Tensorflow using softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits and "soft" labels/targets

Tags: tensorflow, classification

I've found what is probably a rare case in Tensorflow, but I'm trying to train a classifier (linear or nonlinear) using KL divergence (cross entropy) as the cost function in Tensorflow, with soft targets/labels (labels that form a valid probability distribution but are not "hard" 1 or 0).

However it is clear (tell-tail signs) that something is definitely wrong.  I've tried both linear and nonlinear (dense neural network) forms, but no matter what I always get the same final value for my loss function regardless of network architecture (even if I train only a bias).  Also, the cost function converges extremely quickly (within like 20-30 iterations) using L-BFGS (a very reliable optimizer!).  Another sign something is amiss is that I can't overfit the data, and the validation set appears to have exactly the same loss value as the training set.  However, strangely I do see *some* improvements when I increase network architecture size and/or change regularization loss. The accuracy improves with this as well (although not to the point that I'm happy with it or it's as I expect).

It DOES work as expected when I use the exact same code but send in one-hot encoded labels (not soft targets).  An example of the cost function from training taken from Tensorboard is shown below. Can someone pitch me some ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ahh my friend, you're problem is that with soft targets, especially ones that aren't close to 1 or zero, cross entropy loss doesn't change significantly as the algorithm improves.  One thing that will help you understand this problem is to take an example from your training data and compute the entropy....then you will know what the lowest value your cost function can be.  This may shed some light on your problem.  So for one of your examples, let's say the targets are [0.39019628, 0.44301641, 0.16678731].  Well, using the formula for cross entropy

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

but then using the targets "y_" in place of the predicted probabilities "y" we arrive at the true entropy value of 1.0266190072458234.  If you're predictions are just slightly off of target....lets say they are [0.39511779, 0.44509024, 0.15979198], then the cross entropy is 1.026805558049737.

Now, as with most difficult problems, it's not just one thing but a combination of things.  The loss function is being implemented correctly, but you made the "mistake" of doing what you should do in 99.9% of cases when training deep learning algorithms....you used 32-bit floats.  In this particular case though, you will run out of significant digits that a 32-bit float can represent well before you training algorithm converges to a nice result.  If I use your exact same data and code but only change the data types to 64-bit floats though, you can see below that the results are much better -- your algorithm continues to train well out past 2000 iterations and you will see it reflected in your accuracy as well.  In fact, you can see from the slope if 128 bit floating point was supported, you could continue training and probably see advantages from it.  You wouldn't probably need that precision in your final weights and biases...just during training to support continuing optimization of the cost function.

[image]

Comment: I don't see "much better', I see "y-axis scale change".

Comment: L-BFGS is no longer stopping the optimization at 20-30 iterations.  It is continuing due to finding a decreasing cost function out well past 2000 iterations now.  This is indeed reflected in the results, which I have not posted here due to brevity and probably unnecessary detail.

Comment: I should additionally note if it wasn't clear, this was using the same network architecture, data, and random seed as before changing to 64-bit floating points.  So it is a legit one-to-one comparison.